# issue with a smarty nested foreach loop

Tags: php, smarty

The variable I am stating with is a string of HTML code. I am trying to explode on "line break", then explode the result on a "|".
here is the code I am using

```
{assign var="featuresdescarray" value="<br />"|explode:$product.featuresdesc}
{foreach from=$featuresdescarray key=k item=i}
    {assign var="featuresdescarrayexploded" value="|"|explode:$i}
    {foreach from=$featuresdescarrayexploded key=key item=item}
        {if $item eq "yes"}
            yes-textreplaced
        {elseif $item eq "no"}
            no-textreplaced
        {else}
            {$item}<br />
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

So the fist time through the nested foreach the text gets replaced as I expect. after that it seems to fail the if, elseif and just use the else every time.

If i take out the if statement and put in a {$key} : {$item}
 line it looks like it should work.

Not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

OK I am not sure why this works and the original code does not but here is what is working for anyone trying something like this.

I took out the yes and no and replaced it with 1 and 0

```
{assign var="featuresdescarray" value="<br />"|explode:$product.featuresdesc}
    {foreach from=$featuresdescarray key=k item=i}
        {if $i|strstr:"|"}
            {assign var="featuresdescarrayexploded" value="|"|explode:$i}
                {foreach from=$featuresdescarrayexploded key=key item=item}
                    {if $key eq 0 and $item eq 1}
                        <div class="productFeatureDescYes">{$featuresdescarrayexploded[1]}<br /></div>
                    {elseif $key eq 0 and $item eq 0}
                        <div class="productFeatureDescNo">{$featuresdescarrayexploded[1]}<br /></div>
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
            {else}
                {$i}<br />
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
```

I added a if statement to search the variable $i for a "|" if it has one then it is exploded and wrapped in the proper div. if not it is just displayed (to be wrapped in a div later).

I also run the if statement on the key[0] section in the second foreach statement.

The danger of self taught coding i guess, sometime it is just trial and error but I always like to find out what i did wrong and this time it is not the case.

I am not sure why the 0's and 1's worked better then "no" and "yes" so if anyone can answer the original question that would be great.